# Does Flask copy app.config for every request?

Tags: multithreading, flask

According to [the Flask documentation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/appcontext/#lifetime-of-the-context),

> Flask automatically pushes an application context when handling a
> request.... Typically, an application context will have the same lifetime as a request.

Does this mean that objects stored inside `app.config` or `g` are copied for each request?

If not, I suppose that `app.config` and `g` are not thread-safe?

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge now, `g` is created and destroyed during a request. You can't add things onto `g` when initializing the application. It is not used or copied across requests.

In contrast, `app.config` can be used to store application-global values. You can add anything onto it when initializing the application, and then access those values whenever `app` or `flask.current_app` are available.

I'm still unsure if `app` is shared or copied when the Flask dev server or another WSGI server is multithreaded.